# How can I store a 2-dimensional array into cookies?

Tags: reactjs, cookies

I'm trying to save my states into the cookies using the [react-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie) package. It's ok when I want to store some strings into the cookie but my problem is when it comes to saving arrays. For example, I have an array with the below structure:

```
const arr = [
      ['correct','correct','absent'],
      ['present','correct','present'],
      ['absent','absent','correct']
]
```

And now I want to store it into the cookie with the below code:

```
setCookie("states",arr);
```

When I tried to get states from the cookie with `cookies.states` I just got an object with `correct,correct,absent,present,correct,present,absent,absent,correct` result.

Here is my question:
How can I store a 2-dimensional array into cookies and get it with array type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works well with strings did you try to stringify it before saving ?

```
setCookie("states", JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try serializing your data before saving and parsing when reading:

when writing:

```
setCookie("states", JSON.stringify(arr))
```

when reading:

```
const arrFromCookie = JSON.parse(get("states"))
```